# Should a tag for "baby-proofing" be added? Is it a synonym of "safety"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A suggestion was made in chat to add two new synonyms for [safety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety): [baby-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-proofing) and [child-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-proofing).

Should these be added?

Should [baby-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-proofing) and [child-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-proofing) be synonyms of each other, or should they cover discrete age ranges, much like [infant](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infant), [toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toddler), [pre-schooler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-schooler), etc.?

Should either or both of those be made into a synonym for [safety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety)?

Answer (score 2):

I feel that it would make sense to put them all in one bucket, so **I agree with the proposed suggestion:** make *baby/child-proofing* synonyms of *safety.*

We currently have 64 questions tagged *safety.* If we introduce *baby/child-proofing* as tags in their own right, then some of those existing questions need to be re-tagged. I see these options:

**0 new tags:** **-proofing* are synonyms of *safety.*
Pro: no re-tagging needed, amount of content remains manageable.
Con: I can't think of any drawback. I don't see it as a problem that *safety* and **-proofing* aren't separated.

**1 new tag:** *child-proofing,* with *baby-proofing* as a synonym.
Pro: ?
Con: Need to re-tag existing questions. Room for ambiguity on when to use this tag vs. *safety,* or when to use both.

**2 new tags:** *child-proofing* and *baby-proofing* are separate tags.
Pro: fine-grained.
Con: Too fine-grained; I don't see the need to separate them. Also, this would leave room for ambiguity on which one of the tags to use, and also when to add *safety*.

Comment: I took a look at the questions currently tagged [tag:safety].  9 of them are clearly about baby/child-proofing the home (one is a duplicate). 6 or 7 more are about safety specific to around the house, and could arguably be tagged baby/child-proofing. This seems to supports my belief that baby/child-proofing is a strict subset of [tag:safety] (i.e. any question tagged baby/child-proofing would also be tagged safety, but not all safety questions would be tagged baby/child-proofing.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion:

Yes, add [baby-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-proofing).

[child-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-proofing) should be a synonym of [baby-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-proofing)

Neither should be a synonym for [safety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety).